# How to get the indexpath of a custom table view cell when an UIImage inside of it is tapped and captured by UITapGestureRecognizer in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue, uitapgesturerecognizer

Ok a lot of variables in the title, sorry I couldn't make it any more simpler.

First, I have a custom table cell with descriptions like so

[image]

now, when a user taps on the cell itself, it would go to View A,
however, there is a UITapGestureRecognizer that is connected to the UIImage at the left, which is connected to a segue that goes to View B.

All is fine, but I need some data that is inside the table view cell that I can pass to View B so it can do some stuff once the view is shown.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "toViewA") {

    }else if( segue.identifier == "toViewBFromThatImage" ){

        let viewBVC = ( segue.destinationViewController as! viewBVC )
        ///////sender is UITapGestureRecognizer 
        ///////somehow want to get indexpath here

         viewBVC.selectedIndex = SOMEHOW DIRREVED INDEXPATH
    }
}
```

Perhaps I should just set something as a tag of UIImage or the gesture object when initializing? Or should I avoid trying to do this in prepareForSegue in the first place?

Still new to this so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that putting the segue inside the table view cell is the wrong place.  It belongs in the view controller, with a delegate method invoked on the view controller to perform it.

Declare a protocol in your cell subclass -

```
protocol MyCustomCellDelegate {
    func imageTappedInCell(cell:MyCustomCell)
}
```

Then declare a `delegate` property and use it in your gesture recogniser -

```
class MyCustomCell {

    weak var delegate : MyCustomCellDelegate?

    ...

   func imageTapped(recognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

       if (recognizer.state == .Ended) {
           delegate?.imageTapped(self)
       }

   }
```

Then in your view controller you can implement the delegate method.  In the delegate method you can use the cell to identify the index path

```
 class MyTableViewController: UIViewController,MyCustomCellDelegate {


     func imageTapped(cell:MyCustomCell) {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toViewBFromThatImage",sender:cell)
     }

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if( segue.identifier == "toViewBFromThatImage" ){
            let viewBVC = ( segue.destinationViewController as! viewBVC )
            let senderCell=sender as! MyCustomCell
            viewBVC.selectedIndex = self.tableview.indexPathForCell(senderCell)!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realised, what I didn't show was in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will need to set `cell.delegate=self`

Comment: I'm stuck on how to have the gesture recognizer hook up to imageTapped in MyCellView, do I need to set an outlet an delegate to it?Can't seen to associate the two.

Comment: You can't associate a UIGestureRecognizer with a prototype cell in Interface Builder, unfortunately.  You will need to do it in code when you initialise the cell with something like `imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self action:"imageTapped:"))`

Comment: Thanks, this not only gave me a answer to my problems but better practices on design on segues and tap gestures.