# How can I get indexPath of a uiview on a cell - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view controller with a table view. Each cell has a custom view with a five star rating system. I handle touchesBegan of the view at the class of the view

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self handleTouchAtLocation:touchLocation];

}
```

How can I get the indexPath in order to know on which cell user voted? I don't have a button I have a uiview so I cannot use the following:

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
```

Comment: The correct approach is to handle your touch in the cell class and use a delegate to pass the information back to your tableview - here is a similar answer in Swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093596/how-to-get-the-indexpath-of-a-custom-table-view-cell-when-an-uiimage-inside-of-i/33093864#33093864

Comment: I think you should create a property to hold that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your index path in your custom view when you create the view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` by making a property in the class of the view. The property can be set in your init for the custom view. The index path will then be available in your `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method by reading the property.

Answer (score 10):

Do one thing

Give gesture to that view  inside cell for row at index path

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnView:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[viewnanme addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and to handle tap gesture

```
-(void)tappedOnView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:tableView];
NSIndexPath *ipath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
UITableViewCell *cellindex  = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: ipath];
}
```

Swift 3+

```
var singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tappedOnView))
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
viewnanme.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)


func tapped(onView gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: tableView)
    let ipath: IndexPath? = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    let cellindex: UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: ipath!)
}
```

Swift 4+

```
var singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(self.tappedOnView))
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
viewnanme.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

func tapped(onView gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) 
{
    let location: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: tableView)
    let ipath: IndexPath? = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
    let cellindex: UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: ipath ?? 
 IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
}
```

Hope this will help to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

In `cellforAtIndexPath` keep view's tag as `indexPath.row` and in below method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

fetch `UItableViewCell` according to that view tag

Answer (score 0):

There is a given delegate method of UITableView i.e cellForRowIndexPath:.
There is no need to add any Tap Gesture or touchesBegan: method in your code. TableView already has this. You can get index path for the selected cell in this method cellFor RowIndexPath:.